# Unable to execute LIKE query in HSQLDB

Tags: jira, hsqldb, jira-plugin

I need to execute LIKE query. i have created as below:

```
AData ad : ao.find(AData.class, Query.select().where("user=? AND ISSUES LIKE %?%",user,issueId)))      //issues field contain values as //"FIN-1,FIN-2,FIN7". issueId parameter has value as FIN-7
```

it gives me below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: % in statement [SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.AO_0371A8_ADATA WHERE    user=? AND ISSUES LIKE %?%]
```

Updated the query below as :

```
AData ad : ao.find(AData.class, Query.select().where("user=? AND ISSUES LIKE '%? %'",user,issueId)))  //issues field contain values as //"FIN-1,FIN-2,FIN7". issueId parameter has
```

value as FIN-7

it gives me below error: ( parameter index out of range: 2) (Also tried as ".......LIKE \'%?%\'"... but give me same error as below:

```
com.atlassian.activeobjects.internal.ActiveObjectsSqlException: There was a SQL exception thrown  by the Active Objects library:
 Database:
- name:HSQL Database Engine
- version:1.8.0
- minor version:8
- major version:1
 Driver:
- name:HSQL Database Engine Driver
- version:1.8.0

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 2
    at    com.atlassian.activeobjects.internal.EntityManagedActiveObjects.find(EntityManagedActiveObjects.java:   153)
  at    com.atlassian.activeobjects.osgi.DelegatingActiveObjects.find(DelegatingActiveObjects.java:81)  <+3>   (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
   at   org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:58)
    at     org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.j    ava:62)
 at        org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:   171)
  ......
  ..
   .
```

When tried below queries:

```
AData ad : ao.find(AData.class, Query.select().where("user=? AND ISSUES LIKE '%?%'  ",user,issueId)))
```

and also other way,

```
     AData ad : ao.find(AData.class, Query.select().where("user=? AND ISSUES LIKE ? ",user, "%" +   
issueId + "%")))
```

In above both cases, got below error: (Mainly error says, "    java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 2").

```
Uncaught exception thrown by REST service
com.atlassian.activeobjects.internal.ActiveObjectsSqlException: There was a SQL exception thrown     by the Active Objects library:
Database:
- name:HSQL Database Engine
- version:1.8.0
- minor version:8
- major version:1
Driver:
- name:HSQL Database Engine Driver
- version:1.8.0

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 2
at     com.atlassian.activeobjects.internal.EntityManagedActiveObjects.find(EntityManagedActiveObjects.java:    153)
at     com.atlassian.activeobjects.osgi.DelegatingActiveObjects.find(DelegatingActiveObjects.java:81)  <+3>     (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.do
....
```

How it could be working.. what is wrong in this LIKE query?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Updated : The argument to LIKE is an SQL string. You use single quotes for strings in SQL.

You can replace the whole argument with a parameter marker.

You then supply values for two parameter. The value for the second parameter should be a string which can include wildcard elements. This example looks correct.

```
AData ad : ao.find(AData.class, Query.select().where("user=? AND ISSUES LIKE ?",user, "%" + issueId + "%")))
```

Comment: I have updated question above to include result of above query, (please refer last query and error in above original comment). Mainly, it raises an error as "    java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 2". Actually, already provided two param arguments and two ? are there. though raising this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL-like syntax you have in your code above:

```
where("user=? AND ISSUES LIKE %?%",user,issueId)
```

The '%' wildcard character is valid only when used within a quoted literal or in a supplied parameter string.  The usage "LIKE %?%" is invalid.  Replace it with:

```
ISSUES LIKE ?
```

If a parameter to this statement is 'THO', you'll need to modify it to become '%THO%' in order to get the wildcard function that I believe you had intended (eg. LIKE ? with the parameter set to '%THO%' would match ALTHOUGH, THOUGHTFUL, and FATHOM).